# How to combine 2 or more JavaScript with the same function

Tags: javascript

I'm using JS for adapting text in multiple languages, basing on visitors' language. It there any way to shorten this, by combining the code?
That's always following the same pattern, so I guess there's a way (I'm newbie)

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementById('mainphrase');
{ if (italian || french || german)
{ el.innerHTML = (
(italian && '<strong><em>Buongiorno</em></strong>') ||
(french && '<strong><em>Bonjour</em></strong>') ||
(german && '<strong><em>Guten Morgen</em></strong>') ); }
else { el.innerHTML = '<strong><em>Good morning</em></strong>';}
}
</script>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('registerphrase');
{ if (italian || french || german)
{ el.innerHTML = (
(italian && '<strong><em>clicca qui</em></strong>') ||
(french && '<strong><em>clicquer ici
(german && '<strong><em>hier clicken
else { el.innerHTML = '<strong><em>click here</em></strong>';}
}
</script>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('textphrase');
{ if (italian || french || german)
{ el.innerHTML = (
(italian && '<strong><em>Ciao a tutti</em></strong>') ||
(french && '<strong><em>Salut a tous</em></strong>') ||
(german && '<strong><em>Guten Tag</em></strong>') ); }
else { el.innerHTML = '<strong><em>Hello World</em></strong>';}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Search for internalization, with this keyword you can find different approaches to solve your problem. Sorry currently on mobile, don't have any specific link at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    // assuming your variables 'italian', 'french', 'german' already are declared and have values 
    const modifyElHTML = (elID, phrases) => {
        const el = document.getElementById(elID);

        let phrase;

        if (italian) {
            phrase = phrases.italian;
        } else if (french) {
            phrase = phrases.french;
        } else if (german) {
            phrase = phrases.german;
        } else {
            phrase = phrases.english;
        }

        el.innerHTML = `<strong><em>${phrase}</em></strong>`;
    };

    modifyElHTML('mainphrase', {
        italian: 'Buongiorno',
        french: 'Bonjour',
        german: 'Guten Morgen',
       english: 'Good morning'
    });

    modifyElHTML('registerphrase', {
        italian: 'clicca qui',
        french: 'clicquer ici',
        german: 'hier clicken',
        english: 'click here'
    });

    modifyElHTML('textphrase', {
        italian: 'Ciao a tutti',
        french: 'Salut a tous',
        german: 'Guten Tag',
        english: 'Hello World'
    });
</script>
```

You can further shorten this by combining all the 3 calls into 1 call, and all the phrases and id's together, but that might make it a little hard to work with later.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
        let language = {italian:'Buongiorno',german:'Guten Morgen',french:'Bonjour'}
let language1 = {italian:'clicca qui',german:'hier clicken',french:'clicquer ici'} 
         function htmlById(elementId,languageText){
        var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
         if (italian || french || german)
        { el.innerHTML = (
        (italian && '<strong><em>'+languageText.italian+'</em></strong>') ||
        (french && '<strong><em>'+languageText.french+'</em></strong>') ||
        (german && '<strong><em>'+languageText.german+'</em></strong>') ); }
        else { el.innerHTML = '<strong><em>Good morning</em></strong>';}
        }
    htmlById('mainphrase',language)
    htmlById('registerphrase',language1)
        
        </script>
```

using function you can group common functionality without rewriting logic again and again.

Comment: I think you missed one part: lets take as example just english, you have icluded the good morning variant, but missed click here and hello world, that were supposed to be called respectively by htmlById('registerphrase') and htmlById('textphrase')

Comment: yeah I was working on that part for you. I have updated answer have a look. its little rough but will create variable of language with object and you will be able to add different languages

Comment: It's still based on one phrase per language only, so I still don't understand where to put the variants (clicca qui, clicquer ici, hier clicken, click here for 'registerphrase' id; and (ciao a tutti, salut a tous, guten tag, hello world) for 'textphrase' id

Comment: you declare variable for every variant and pass it to function like
let language = {italian:'Buongiorno',german:'Guten Morgen',french:'Bonjour'}
let language1 = {italian:'clicca qui',german:'hier clicken',french:'clicquer ici'}